# Github icon in latex

Tags: templates, latex

I have resume template on overleaf. Now I want to add github logo on that after linkdein logo. How can I do that?

https://www.overleaf.com/articles/aditya-gadepallis-resume/kzdksnkdcrsr

How I want to add github logo after linkdein logo.

I am confused how to do that can someone please help me in that.

This is the tex file : https://pastebin.com/qVJ7HViy

This is the cls file : https://pastebin.com/AX27WY7e

```
\ProvidesClass{twentysecondcv}[2017/01/08 CV class]
\LoadClass{article}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    REQUIRED PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{ifmtarg}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    COLOURS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    MISC CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\color{gray}} % Make \textbf produce coloured text instead

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Disable paragraph indentation

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SIDEBAR DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm} % Left margin
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm} % Top margin

\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{5cm}
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/600}

\newlength{\TotalSectionLength} % Define a new length to hold the remaining line width after the section title is printed
\newlength{\SectionTitleLength} % Define a new length to hold the width of the section title
\newcommand{\profilesection}[1]{%
    \setlength\TotalSectionLength{\linewidth}% Set the total line width
    \settowidth{\SectionTitleLength}{\huge #1 }% Calculate the width of the section title
    \addtolength\TotalSectionLength{-\SectionTitleLength}% Subtract the section title width from the total width
    \addtolength\TotalSectionLength{-2.22221pt}% Modifier to remove overfull box warning
    \vspace{8pt}% Whitespace before the section title
    {\color{black!80} \huge #1 \rule[0.15\baselineskip]{\TotalSectionLength}{1pt}}% Print the title and auto-width rule
}

% Define custom commands for CV info
\newcommand{\cvdate}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvdate}{#1}}

\newcommand{\cvnumberphone}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvnumberphone}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvaddress}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvaddress}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvsite}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvsite}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Education}[1]{\renewcommand{\Education}{#1}}
\newcommand{\skills}[1]{\renewcommand{\skills}{#1}}
\newcommand{\COURSEWORK}[1]{\renewcommand{\COURSEWORK}{#1}}


\newcommand{\cvname}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvname}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvjobtitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvjobtitle}{#1}}

% Command for printing the contact information icons
\newcommand*\icon[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=mainblue,mainblue,text=white] (char) {#1};}}

% Command for printing skill progress bars


% Command for printing skills text
\newcommand\skillstext[1]{ 
    \renewcommand{\skillstext}{
        \begin{flushleft}
            \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{ 
                \x$ \star $\y
            }
        \end{flushleft}
    }
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SIDEBAR LAYOUT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\makeprofile}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \begin{textblock}{6}(0.5, 0.2)

        %------------------------------------------------

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\profilepic}{}}{}{
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
                    \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);
                    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{\profilepic}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
        }

        %------------------------------------------------

        {\Huge\color{mainblue}\cvname}

        %------------------------------------------------

        {\Large\color{black!80}\cvjobtitle}

        %------------------------------------------------

        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} @{\hskip 0.5cm}p{5cm}}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \cvdate\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \cvaddress\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvnumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \cvnumberphone\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \cvsite\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\cvmail}{\cvmail}}
        \end{tabular}

        %------------------------------------------------

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\Education}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{Education}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \Education
            \end{flushleft}
        }

        %------------------------------------------------
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\skills}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{Skills}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \skills
            \end{flushleft}
        }

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\COURSEWORK}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{COURSEWORK}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \COURSEWORK
            \end{flushleft}
        }




        %------------------------------------------------

    \end{textblock}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    COLOURED SECTION TITLE BOX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Command to create the rounded boxes around the first three letters of section titles
\newcommand*\round[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=north west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=1.6pt, minimum size=5.5mm, text height=3.6mm, fill=#2,#2,text=white](char){#1};%
}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\newcommand{\sectioncolor}[1]{%
    {%
        \round{#1}{
            \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\else%
            maingray\fi%
        }%
    }%
    \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    {%
        \color{gray}%
        \Large\sectioncolor{#1}%
    }
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
    \par\vspace{.5\parskip}{%
        \large\color{gray} #1%
    }
    \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    LONG LIST ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% New environment for the long list
\newenvironment{twenty}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.83\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\footnotesize#3}\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}%
    }\\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SMALL LIST ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% New environment for the small list
\newenvironment{twentyshort}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\twentyitemshort}[2]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.83\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
    }\\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    MARGINS AND LINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=7.6cm,top=0.1cm,right=1cm,bottom=0.2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. And [edit] your question to give some precisions. What is *exactly* your problem?

Comment: crosspost: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498458/github-icon-in-latex

Answer (score 5):

Quick hack:

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Twenty Seconds Resume/CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (8/1/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Carmine Spagnuolo (cspagnuolo@unisa.it) with major modifications by 
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% The MIT License (see included LICENSE file)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% If you don't need one or more of the below, just remove the content leaving the command, e.g. \cvnumberphone{}



\cvname{Aditya} % Your name
\cvjobtitle{Gadepalli} % Job title/career

\cvdate{16 February 1997} % Date of birth
\cvaddress{adityagadepalli@gmail.com} % Short address/location, use \newline if more than 1 line is required
\cvnumberphone{+91 9553336954} % Phone number
\cvsite{linkedin.com/in/a-gadepalli} % Personal website
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cvmail}{example@mail.com}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\renewcommand{\makeprofile}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \begin{textblock}{6}(0.5, 0.2)

        %------------------------------------------------

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\profilepic}{}}{}{
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
                    \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);
                    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{\profilepic}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
        }

        %------------------------------------------------

        {\Huge\color{mainblue}\cvname}

        %------------------------------------------------

        {\Large\color{black!80}\cvjobtitle}

        %------------------------------------------------

        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} @{\hskip 0.5cm}p{5cm}}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \cvdate\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \cvaddress\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvnumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \cvnumberphone\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\scalebox{0.85}{\faLinkedin}}} & \url{linkedin.com/in/a-gadepalli}\\}
            \textsc{\Large\icon{\scalebox{0.8}{\faGithub}}} &  \url{https://github.com}\\
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\cvmail}{\cvmail}}
        \end{tabular}

        %------------------------------------------------

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\Education}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{Education}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \Education
            \end{flushleft}
        }

        %------------------------------------------------
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\skills}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{Skills}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \skills
            \end{flushleft}
        }

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\ExtraCurricular}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{Extra-Curricular}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \ExtraCurricular
            \end{flushleft}
        }




        %------------------------------------------------

    \end{textblock}
}


\makeatother
\newcommand{\profilepic}{example-image-duck}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Education
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\Education{B.E.(Hons.) Mechanical Engineering BITS Pilani | 2018 | GPA:8.947/10
\newline \newline Class XII \newline  Mahathi Jr College | 2014 | 95.7 \%
\newline \newline Class X \newline  Rishi Vid. Gurukulam | 2012 | 10/10} % To have no Education section, just remove all the text and leave \Education{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Skill bar section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6 (float)
\skills{Languages: C, Java, Matlab, SQL, Gosu, Basics of R and Python 
\newline  WebDev : HTML, CSS, JS, JQuery, php  
\newline  Simulation :  Ansys, Comsol, Arduino 
\newline  Design : ProE, AutoCAD, Solidworks, Autodesk Alias, Adobe Photoshop
\newline  Other: MS Office, JIRA, Git, Adobe AE 
\newline Certifications: Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE 8 Programmer}



\ExtraCurricular{Co-Founder \& Head @ Evolve  \\ - Organized talks \& workshops 
\\ - Brought the alumni of IITs, BITS, NITs and industry professionals to guide students
\newline\newline Graphic Designer @ Designers Anonymous \& Dept. of Technical Arts\\- Taught design softwares to students\\- Designed content to publicize fests
\newline \newline Event Manager @ BITS Embryo \\ - Organizer of conclave forums \& talks\\
- Handled logistics \& pitched speakers 
\newline\newline Volunteer @ NSS \& Nirmaan NGO \\ - Created jobs for rural women\\- Co-organized Cyclone relief fund-raiser, cleanliness drives \& taught rural school kids
\newline\newline Class Committee representative \& Teaching Assistant for the courses Production Techniques \& Human Resource Development}

%------------------------------------------------

% Skill text section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeprofile % Print the sidebar

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    INTERESTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experience and Internships}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem{Since Aug'18}{Senior Analyst}{Capgemini, Hyderabad}{Building a Rating Engine for Insurance firms using Guidewire \& Java}
    \twentyitem{Jan-Jun'18}{Research Intern}{Center for AI \& Robotics, DRDO,  Bengaluru}{Designed \& built a Stair Climber bot along with its basic SDK library\\ Worked on Active Noise Cancellation algorithms for Wall Climber bot}
    \twentyitem{July'17}{Summer Intern}{NTPC Limited, Solapur}{Analyed \emph{Scope of Wind capacity installations} using Meteorological data and learnt about the practical challenges of commissioning them}
    \twentyitem{June'17}{Summer Intern}{RINL, Visakhapatnam}{Learnt about steel making processes \& waste heat recovery systems\\ Analyzed workflow \& suggested optimization of few bottlenecks}

    \twentyitem{Summer'16}{Summer Intern}{Century Rayon, Mumbai}{Investigated the "Heating Effects in Cake conditioning Rooms"\\
 Studied TQM and DMAIC  practices to address performance issues}


    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Research and Projects}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
    \twentyitem{May-Dec'17}{Advanced Materials for Energy Efficient Buildings} {}{Studied the application of Phase Change Materials in buildings to \\reduce cooling load \& energy usage across various geographies}
    \twentyitem{Jan-May'17}{Design of Cleanroom for MEMS Fabrication}{}{Optimized the control parameters of an ISO 5 Cleanroom using DOE methods \& COMSOL5.1 (CFD) \& validated results with Hemair SI Ltd.}
    \twentyitem{Jan-May'17}{Interactive Creation of Splines}{}{Formulated algorithms and built a GUI using Matlab to obtain splines and their respective blending functions for any given dynamic input}
    \twentyitem{Aug-Nov'16}{Fabrication of Tabletop EDM Machine}{}{Led a team of 8 students to design \& build the product from genesis \&
achieved 20 micron erosion on AISI 1020 steel using brass electrode}
    \twentyitem{Aug-Nov'15}{Critical analysis of Performance appraisal systems}{}{Led a team of 8 students to survey \& review the appraisal systems of NTPC and IBM to measure its influence on employee's work outputs}
    %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    AWARDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Achievements}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
    \twentyitem{Dec'17}{Book Distribution Campaign}{}{Single handedly ran a campaign \& sold over 150+ books within 3 days}
    \twentyitem{Mar'17}{First - VIKAS Soch Ideation Marathon}{}{Won 10k in cash for best social startup idea at Launchpad E-Summit}
    \twentyitem{Mar'16}{Runners Up - Ground Reality}{}{Won 12k in cash for the best B-Plan submission at Pearl 2017}
    \twentyitem{Feb'10}{Best All Rounder Award}{}{Ranked first across all campuses of school for all-round excellence}
    \twentyitem{2010-11}{Olympiads(School Level)}{}{GOLD Medals won at NSO(2011), NCO(2010) \& IMO(2010))}
    %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Electives and MOOCs}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions

    \twentyitem{Electives}{Reverse Engineering \& Rapid Prototyping, Renewable Energy, Quality Control Assurance \& Reliability, Project Appraisal, Public Policy,\\Principles of Management, HR Development, Fundamentals of\\Finance \& Accounting, Srimad Bhagavad Gita}{}{}
    \twentyitem{MOOCs}{\textbf{Introduction to R,SQL \& Python Courses on Datacamp}\\Currently pursuing Deep Learning Specialization on Coursera}{}{}

    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    OTHER INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SECOND PAGE EXAMPLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\newpage % Start a new page

%\makeprofile % Print the sidebar

%\section{Other information}

%\subsection{Review}

%Alice approaches Wonderland as an anthropologist, but maintains a strong sense of noblesse oblige that comes with her class status. She has confidence in her social position, education, and the Victorian virtue of good manners. Alice has a feeling of entitlement, particularly when comparing herself to Mabel, whom she declares has a ``poky little house," and no toys. Additionally, she flaunts her limited information base with anyone who will listen and becomes increasingly obsessed with the importance of good manners as she deals with the rude creatures of Wonderland. Alice maintains a superior attitude and behaves with solicitous indulgence toward those she believes are less privileged.

%\section{Other information}

%\subsection{Review}

%Alice approaches Wonderland as an anthropologist, but maintains a strong sense of noblesse oblige that comes with her class status. She has confidence in her social position, education, and the Victorian virtue of good manners. Alice has a feeling of entitlement, particularly when comparing herself to Mabel, whom she declares has a ``poky little house," and no toys. Additionally, she flaunts her limited information base with anyone who will listen and becomes increasingly obsessed with the importance of good manners as she deals with the rude creatures of Wonderland. Alice maintains a superior attitude and behaves with solicitous indulgence toward those she believes are less privileged.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: @manu The file you added to the question seems to be the same broken one with missing command definitions. So my answer should still work.

Comment: Hi @samsarter, could you please help me to [change cvname font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553631/how-to-change-font-size-of-cvname-of-twentysecondcv-class-in-latex).

Comment: @JayPrakashThakur Please stop pinging so many other users. These are volunteers, pinging them like this is considered rude. Imagine everybody would do it!

Comment: @JayPrakashThakur I could try if you would post a [mre], e.g. a small test document that has `\documentclass`, all the necessary package etc.

Comment: `\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} \cvname{Jay Prakash Thakur} % Your name` . this name is a little larger. so I was thinking to change font size to make it shorter.

Comment: @JayPrakashThakur The point is that I don't want to spend time first to puzzle together code fragment and guess the missing pieced before I can even start working on your problem. Make a ready to copy&paste document and I'll have a look. And don't post it in comments, edit your question to include it

Comment: @samcarter [here is overhear template](https://www.overleaf.com/4428849587ykwrkphydjnz)

Comment: @JayPrakashThakur Please add a small test document to your question. External links will be useless for any future users that might have the same problem as you.

Comment: @samcarter ohh. thank you so much for guidance. I have updated [the link](https://www.overleaf.com/4428849587ykwrkphydjnz)

Comment: @JayPrakashThakur Please add a small but compilable document to your questions on stackoverflow. Don't link to external websites.